# Can I distinguish between these two dismiss actions for alertdialog in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-alertdialog, android-jetpack-compose

I am a beginner of Jetpack compose. Now in my app screen, an `AlertDialog` is used to show some information to user.

According to doc, `onDismissRequest` is invoked when the user clicks outside the dialog or on the back button.

But I just want to dismiss it when back button is pressed, but not dissmiss when outside touched, how can I distinguish between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I just want to dismiss it when the back button is pressed, but not dismiss when outside touched

Use the `properties` attribute in `AlertDialog` like this.

```
AlertDialog(
    properties = DialogProperties(
        dismissOnClickOutside = false,
        dismissOnBackPress = true,
    ),
)
```